# Oracle PL/SQL package errors (ORA-04063 and ORA-06508) when called from a java application

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I run my application and call a PL/SQL package, I get the errors:

> ORA-04063: package body "SEARCH_TRAILER" has
>   errors ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
>   "SEARCH_TRAILER" ORA-06512: at line 1

I replaced the package body and package spec and successfully recompiled yet I still get the error. There are other stored procedures called within this stored procedure.  But if it was only of those stored procedures wouldn't the error call that stored procedure instead of the one that is called by the application?
Is there any thing I need to look at to resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like package 'SEARCH_TRAILER' has errors. Are you sure the header and the body were compiled successfully?

Comment: After recompile in Pl/Sql you sometimes need to exit and start a new session to get rid of the 6508 error. This is an annoying behavior but that the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the compilation errors. If you're using an IDE like SQL Developer  then there's a tab for that. If you're using SQL*Plus you should get the errors with the `show errors` command.

In any environment you can always run this:

```
 select * from user_errors
 where name = 'SEARCH_TRAILER'
```

(assuming you're connected as the package owner, otherwise use ALL_ERRORS).